# Highcharts: Stacked column xAxis "compressing" automatically

Tags: highcharts, jsfiddle

I have a stacked column Highchart with two series.  The xAxis padding, min and max are just how I want them.  jsFiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/BobTheZealot/MBmu7/#base

Series of interest is the second series, which has just one data point:

```
data: [{
        x: 1767157200000,
        y: 95746
    }
```

However, if I add another data point to the second series (x is in 2014 for the new point, well within the previous min and max), the xAxis suddenly "compresses": there is extra padding on either side of the axis, and there are a two more labels on the axis (2010 and 2028).

```
data: [{
        x: 1420002000000,
        y: -95100
    }, {
        x: 1767157200000,
        y: 95746
    }]
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BobTheZealot/MBmu7/13/

Why is the xAxis getting reformatted?  How can I force it look as it does in the first jsFiddle?

Strangely, if I flip the order of the data points of the second series such that they are in descending order of x values (which seems strange; the first series has data in ascending order of x values), then the xAxis formatting doesn't change (i.e., doesn't "compress").

```
data: [{
        x: 1767157200000,
        y: 95746
    }, {
        x: 1420002000000,
        y: -95100
    }
```

jsFiddle at version 14 of previous jsFiddle link (can't post three links, apparently).

Been stuck on this for a couple of days, so would greatly welcome any help!  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is timespan between points. If you know what is ~interval between points, you can set `pointRange`, see: http://jsfiddle.net/MBmu7/15/ otherwise it will take 1767157200000 - 1672462800000 as distance between points and accordingly format xAxis.

Comment: Many thanks Pawel.  That certainly seems to fix it.  I'm just digging around to understand this better since I've encountered the problem elsewhere.

Comment: The pointRange documentation says "computed as the distance between the two closest data points".  1767157200000 and 1672462800000 are actually in all three jsFiddles above.  Could it be using "closest data points" in the SAME series as the pointRange?  So, since there are only two points in the second example above, it's using (1767157200000 - 1420002000000) as the range, which is quite large?  And in the third example, it gets a negative range since the points are in descending order?  Regardless, many thanks.

Comment: In Highcharts you have to order your points ascending. Regarding pointRange, need to probably check sources to get full answer.